# Solving difference equations involving transcendental functions

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

```
v = 0
Solve[Tan[Sqrt[ϵ]]/Sqrt[ϵ] == -Tan[Sqrt[ϵ - v]]/Sqrt[ϵ - v], ϵ]
Solve[Tan[Sqrt[a]]/Sqrt[a] == -Tanh[Sqrt[v - a]]/Sqrt[v - a], a]
```

I want to evaluate `ϵ` or `a` (depending on whether $E>V$ or $E<V$), which is the energy, for different values of `v`.

The code shows error.

Comment: Why do you expect these equations to symbolic solutions?

Comment: The ϵ stands for the energy. The entire question is related to a perturbation theory problem and I need to find energies for various values of the potential v.

Comment: The two solve-equations are identical for `a==eps` ?  Please give a more detailed  description of your question!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  It is a Particle in a box Perturbation Theory problem. ϵ and a are same. ϵ is when E>V and and a is when E<V.

Comment: @tabby_kaur: And you are looking for a solution E~V???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  For different values of V, I need to calculate E. 
V=0, 0.1, 2, 10, 50.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation:

```
eq = Tan[Sqrt[e]]/Sqrt[e] + Tan[Sqrt[e-v]]/Sqrt[e-v] == 0 /. e->e[v];
eq //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\tan \left(\sqrt{e(v)}\right)}{\sqrt{e(v)}}+\frac{\tan
>    \left(\sqrt{e(v)-v}\right)}{\sqrt{e(v)-v}}=0$

When $v=0$, the lowest energy solution occurs at $e=\pi^2$. Here are two approaches:

**Series**

The first approach uses a series approximation of the solution:

```
coeffs = First @ SolveAlways[Series[eq, {v, 0, 10}] /. e[0]->Pi^2, v];
ser = Series[e[v], {v, 0, 10}] /. e[0]->Pi^2 /. coeffs;
ser //TeXForm
```

> $\pi ^2+\frac{v}{2}+\frac{3 v^2}{16 \pi ^2}+\frac{\left(-21-4 \pi ^2\right) v^4}{768 \pi
>    ^6}+\frac{\left(1485+540 \pi ^2+12 \pi ^4\right) v^6}{184320 \pi
>    ^{10}}+\frac{\left(-61425-32760 \pi ^2-2940 \pi ^4-8 \pi ^6\right) v^8}{20643840 \pi
>    ^{14}}+\frac{\left(4578525+3213000 \pi ^2+533925 \pi ^4+16200 \pi ^6+5 \pi ^8\right)
>    v^{10}}{3715891200 \pi ^{18}}+O\left(v^{11}\right)$

The radius of convergence appears to be around 10:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Normal[ser], {v, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

**NDSolve**

The second approach uses [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve):

```
nds = NDSolveValue[{D[eq, v], e[0] == Pi^2}, e, {v, 0, 50}];
```

A comparison:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Normal[ser], nds[v]}], {v, 0, 50}, PlotRange->{10, 35}]
```

[image]

**Multiple energy curves**

My previous answer included a single energy curve. It is possible to extend the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) approach to generate multiple energy curves. First come up with an initial condition:

```
e10 = Flatten @ Values @ NSolve[(eq /. {e[v]->e, v->10}) && 0<e<100]
```

> {5.41955, 16.2171, 27.0198, 44.9177, 66.5967, 94.0307}

Then, use this initial condition in a vectorized [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = Quiet @ NDSolveValue[{D[eq,v], e[10]==%582},e,{v,0,50}];
```

*(I quieted some strange messages)*. Here's a visualization:

```
Plot[sol[v], {v,0,50}, AxesLabel->{V, "E"}]
```

[image]

Note the new low level energy curve below the one in my previous answer.

Comment: How do I calculate the lowest energies for each of the values. Its a little confusing to me.

Comment: @tabby_kaur If you want the energies for $v=20$, use `sol[20]`.

Comment: @Carl Woll: Your NDSolve approach is cool!  Your last plot (level energy curves) should coincide with the result I gave in my answer using ContourPlot. Any idea why this isn't true(despite axes rotation )?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get a symbolic solution, but Contourplot might help on a numerical way:

```
Show[{
Plot[v, {v, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> {\[Epsilon], v}, PlotStyle -> Red]
,
ContourPlot[Tan[Sqrt[\[Epsilon]]]/
 Sqrt[\[Epsilon]] == -Tan[Sqrt[\[Epsilon] - v]]/
 Sqrt[\[Epsilon] - v], {\[Epsilon], 0.001, 50}, {v, \[Epsilon], 
50}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3]
,
ContourPlot[Tan[Sqrt[\[Epsilon]]]/
 Sqrt[\[Epsilon]] == -Tanh[Sqrt[v - \[Epsilon]]]/
 Sqrt[v - \[Epsilon]], {\[Epsilon], 0.001, 50}, {v,0, \[Epsilon]},PlotPoints-> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3,ContourStyle -> {Blue}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to find, where are the exact intersection points, when v=0, 0.1, 2, 10 and 50.